# JQuery Validation Modal Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, bootstrap-modal

I am new to coding and am wracking my brain on this and hope you can help. I am having a bit of trouble solving my registration page.  I am using JQuery validation and a Modal within the page.  I had my validation working correctly but can't seem to get it working with the modal.  What is wrong with my validation coding  What am I missing here to keep it from working?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="/Root/JS/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Root/JS/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Root/JS/contactus-form.js"></script>

<link href="/Root/CSS/newstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Root/CSS/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Root/CSS/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
              <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="signIn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h1 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Registration</h1>
                </div> <!-- close modal header -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="formWrap" >
                        <form id="contactform" name='test' class="form-horizontal contactus" method="post" action='' accept-charset='UTF-8'> 
                        <p><label class="error control-label">* Required Field.</label></p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name<span class="error">*</span></label>

                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="firstname">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="lastname">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Address</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="address">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address"/>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="address2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address2" placeholder="Address (2)"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-xs-3" id="city">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="City"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2" id="state">
                                <select class="form-control" name="state"/>
                                        <option>IN</option>
                                        <option>AL</option>
                                        <option>AR</option>
                                        <option>AZ</option>
                                        <option>CA</option>
                                        <option>CO</option>
                                        <option>CT</option>
                                        <option>DE</option>
                                        <option>FL</option>
                                        <option>GA</option>
                                        <option>IA</option>
                                        <option>ID</option>
                                        <option>IL</option>
                                        <option>KS</option>
                                        <option>KY</option>
                                        <option>LA</option>
                                        <option>MA</option>
                                        <option>MD</option>
                                        <option>ME</option>
                                        <option>MI</option>
                                        <option>MN</option>
                                        <option>MO</option>
                                        <option>MS</option>
                                        <option>MT</option>
                                        <option>NC</option>
                                        <option>ND</option>
                                        <option>NE</option>
                                        <option>NH</option>
                                        <option>NJ</option>
                                        <option>NM</option>
                                        <option>NV</option>
                                        <option>NY</option>
                                        <option>OH</option>
                                        <option>OK</option>
                                        <option>OR</option>
                                        <option>PA</option>
                                        <option>RI</option>
                                        <option>SC</option>
                                        <option>SD</option>
                                        <option>TN</option>
                                        <option>TX</option>
                                        <option>UT</option>
                                        <option>VA</option>
                                        <option>VT</option>
                                        <option>WA</option>
                                        <option>WI</option>
                                        <option>WV</option>
                                        <option>WY</option>
                                </select>           
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3" id="zip">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Phone number<span class="error">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-xs-3" id="cell">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell" placeholder="cell"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3" id="home">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="home" placeholder="home"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Email address<span class="error">*</span></label>     
                            <div class="col-xs-5" id="email">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"/>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password<span class="error">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-xs-5" id="password">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Confirm Password<span class="error">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-xs-5" id="passwordconfirm">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordconfirm"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Real Estate Interest<span class="error">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <div class="checkbox" id="realestate">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Purchase"/>Purchase</label>
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Sell" />Sell</label>           
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Rent" />Rent</label>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-offset-3 g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="###"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
                                <button type="submit" id="contactbtn" class="btn btn-primary" name="register" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <script>
                    $("#contactform").validate();
                    </script>

                    </div> <!--close formWrap -->
                  </div> <!--close modal-body-->
                 </div><!-- close modal content -->
              </div><!-- close modal-dialog -->
            </div>  <!-- close modal-fade -->
         </div> 
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="register" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signIn">Register Here</button>
    </div><!-- end .content -->
</div><!-- end .container -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is my for my contactus-form.js as listed in the html.

```
//Form Validation for Modal
$().ready(function(){
        $("#contactform").validate({
            rules: {

                firstname: "required",
                lastname:  "required",

                cell: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    },

                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                    },

                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 32
                    },

                passwordconfirm: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 32,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                    },

                realestate: {
                    required: true,
                    rangelength: [1,3]
                    },

            messages: {
                firstname:  "Please enter your first name", 
                lastname:   "Please enter last name",

                cell: {
                    required: "Please enter a cell number",
                    minlength: "Please include area code",
                    },

                password: {
                    required: "Please enter a password",
                    minlength: "Password must be between 6 and 32 characters",      maxlength: "Password must be between 6 and 32 characters"               
                    },

                passwordconfirm: {
                    required: "Please re-enter password",
                    minlength: "Password must be between 6 and 32 characters",
                    maxlength: "Password must be between 6 and 32 characters",
                    equalTo: "Password confirm does not email the password" 
                    },

                    realestate:{
                        required: "Please select at least one"
                        },                  

            }
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are using validation on same form more then one time. In this situation only the first call will take effect [multiple jquery validators on one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948155/multiple-jquery-validators-on-one-form) which in your case is `$("#contactform").validate();` and second one will be ignored.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I goofed on my post.  The $("#contactform").validate is both in the html code and it calls the java script contact-form.js.  This is not all on one form as it appears so I still have the problem.  My real question is how do I have my modal come back up after I submit the form?  Also why is my validation not working.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Removing some of your rules, but leaving the structure intact, we can see the problem...

```
$().ready(function(){
        $("#contactform").validate({
            rules: {
                // .... other rules clipped
                realestate: {
                    required: true,
                    rangelength: [1,3]
                    },

            messages: {
                // .... other rules clipped
                    realestate:{
                        required: "Please select at least one"
                        },                  

            }
            }
        });
});
```

You've put the `messages` option *inside* of the `rules` option, thereby breaking the plugin.

**Within the `.validate()` method, `messages` is supposed to be a sibling of `rules`**.

Should look like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contactform").validate({
        rules: {
            // .... other rules
            realestate: {
                required: true,
                rangelength: [1,3]
            }
         }, // <- close 'rules' option
         messages: {
             // .... other rules
             realestate:{
                 required: "Please select at least one"
             }                  
         } // <- close 'messages' option
     });
 });
```

---

You should also fix your DOM ready handler.  `$().ready(function(){...` is *"not recommended"* [as per the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

---

As already stated in the other answer, you **cannot** call `$("#contactform").validate(...)` more than once on the same form.  It does not matter that one is in the HTML.  **Only the first instance is used to initialize the plugin** *and all subsequent instances will be ignored*.  If you made a mistake in posting your OP, then edit it so that we can rule that out as the root cause.